# Pairs of roots of unity whose real part satisfies a polynomial identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, algebraic-number-theory

Some motivation: The matrix $M$ is *Butson Hadamard* if the entries of $M$ are $k^{\textrm{th}}$ roots of unity (for some $k$), and distinct pairs of rows are orthogonal under the usual Hermitian inner product. I am interested in classifying the Butson Hadamard matrices for which some power is a real scalar matrix. (This is equivalent to the corresponding unitary matrix having finite multiplicative order.)

In the case of $2\times 2$ matrices, after some reductions, the problem is equivalent to classifying
the pairs of roots of unity $(\zeta_{1}, \zeta_{2})$ for which

$$\Re( \zeta_{1} ) = \sqrt{2} \Re(\zeta_{2}) $$

This can be restated as $2\Re(\zeta_{2})^{2} - \Re(\zeta_{1})^{2} = 0$. The solutions we have found, up to negation and complex conjugation, are $(i, i)$, $(1, \omega_{8})$ and $(\omega_{8}, \omega_{6})$.
We ran computer searches which suggest that any further solution involves a $k^{\textrm{th}}$ root of unity for some $k \geq 33$.

Q1: Is this list of solutions to the displayed equation complete?

Q2: More generally, what techniques exist for finding all solutions to a polynomial equation in real parts of roots of unity?

Comment: I found no further solutions up to $k \le 10000$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have
  $$ \frac{\zeta_1+\frac{1}{\zeta_1}}{\zeta_2+\frac{1}{\zeta_2}}=\sqrt{2}. $$
By applying Galois group automorphisms we can assume that
  $\zeta_2=e^{2\pi i/n}$ for some $n$, where we can take either value
  of $\sqrt{2}$. Solving for $\zeta_1$ gives
    $$ \sqrt{2}\zeta_1=\zeta_2+\frac{1}{\zeta_2}
    \pm\sqrt{\zeta_2^2+\frac{1}{\zeta_2^2}}. $$
If $n>8$ then $\zeta_2^2+\frac{1}{\zeta_2^2}>0$. This implies that
  $\zeta_1$ is real, a contradiction. Thus there are no further
  solutions.